# Antique Component Identification

Tags: identification, components

Can anyone identify the component in the photos?

[image]    [image]

Comment: Looks like an old selenium rectifier if I had to guess.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_rectifier

Comment: If it smells like rotten eggs it's a (bad) Se rectifier.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a copper oxide rectifier.

[image]

*Image credit:* [Industrial-Electronics.com](https://www.industrial-electronics.com/sams_metallic_4.html)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for catching my misprint!  It has been verified as a selenium rectifier.  Thanks to all!

Comment: It most certainly isn't a silicon rectifier! The silicon rectifier is current and not the obsolete device you have referred to in your question. Here's more information on silicon rectifiers/diodes. https://www.gdrectifiers.co.uk/august-2016-introduction-to-silicon-rectifier-diodes/

Comment: On the other hand, the copper disc confirms it's a copper oxide rectifier.